# AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have a function in mfc(which is a dll type project) which extracts a zip file and creates folder which ultimately show up the files ,now this is used in C#.Net project so when I call this method from dll in the C#.net project not all files are extracted and shows up the error an AccessViolationExceptions occurs .

I guess this buffer which takes the extracted files there at the .net project is not able to allocate that much amount of memory..
I need advice on it ....

```
BYTE *buffer;
buffer = new BYTE[oFileData.lActualSize];
if( buffer == 0 )
{
_tcscpy((*_errorText), szFilesFolder.GetBuffer() );
szFilesFolder.ReleaseBuffer();
CoTaskMemFree((*_errorText));

return FAILTOALLMEM;
}
```

SIGNATURE of the function in mfc :

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int extractCompressedFile( TCHAR* _szFilePath, TCHAR* _extractPath, TCHAR** _errorText )
```

Calling in C#.Net

```
IntPtr BackupDLL = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(somepath);
IntPtr procaddr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(BackupDLL, "extractCompressedFile");
C_ExtractFiles func = (C_ExtractFiles)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procaddr,typeof(C_ExtractFiles));
res = func(Program.ptc_SourFilePath, ptc_DestinationFilePath, ref errtext);
Program.strResult = res.ToString();



static class ExtNativeMethods
{
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [In][MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string procedureName);
}
```

Comment: Update : The dll code was compiled using unicode character set but here the dllimport uses Ansi coding but i tried using Unicode too but no help also with that change I changed UnmanagedType.LPStr to LPWStr but still no help .

Comment: You forgot to post your C_ExtractFiles delegate declaration.  You didn't think it was important so surely it is wrong.  Little point in not just using a [DllImport] btw.